# Angular Custom Directive Does not trigger ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which populates content using ng-repeat. I have an ng-click / ng-focus event on each element inside but the click does not trigger the action.

This works when I remov the ng-repeat from the template. I'm using angularjs 1.3.4

```
app.directive('inputTable', [function(){
      restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div  ng-repeat="item in items"  >
                       <div >
                            <input type="text" ng-focus="focusTap()" ng-model="item.name" placeholder="Name">
                      </div>
                  </div>',
        replace:true,
        scope: {
            items:'=items'
        },
        controller:['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element ){
            $scope.focusTap = function(){
                console.log('focus called');
            }
        }],
        link: ['$scope', '$element', 'attributes', function($scope, $element, attributes){

        }],
}]
```

Comment: Where is the `ng-click`?

Comment: can you please show how youre using this directive?

Comment: yeah, lol where where you? Don't nail the board without a nail and wondering why the nail haven't gone in.

Comment: he said ng-click / ng-focus

Comment: @GilMoshayof

<input-table items="items"></input-table>

ng-repeat works.. but the ng-focus doesnt work.

Comment: Use watch function the get the value. The binding was return on first digest cycle which the ng-repeat haven't finish rendering the DOM. so the value isn't there in the first place. With watch you will see the value being update.

Comment: try replacing items:'=items' with items:'@'

Comment: @GilMoshayof doing that causes duplicates. Throws an error, duplicates in a repeater  are not allowed. Added a track by $index, it ended up showing me more than 10 entries instead of 3!

Comment: @GilMoshayof  it didnt solve my issue  either

Comment: @tasseKATT angularjs 1.3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug. Works as expected in **1.3.0-beta.10**, but not later versions.

If using a newer version then remove `replace: true` and it will work.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/hb5eWfoYH4PCkNaYaxn6?p=preview